# The Mapping Class Group of the Annulus

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, covering-spaces, mapping-class-group

I was reading "A primer on Mapping Class Groups" by B. Farb and D. Margalit and I'm stuck at a point in the proof of Mod$(A)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ where $A$ is the annulus.

Proposition 2.4 $\operatorname{Mod}(A) \approx \mathbb{Z}$.

Proof. First we construct a $\operatorname{map} \rho: \operatorname{Mod}(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. Let $f \in \operatorname{Mod}(A)$ and let $\phi: A \rightarrow A$ be any homeomorphism representing $f$. The universal cover of $A$ is the infinite strip $\widetilde{A} \approx \mathbb{R} \times[0,1]$, and $\phi$ has a preferred lift $\widetilde{\phi}: \widetilde{A} \rightarrow \widetilde{A}$ fixing the origin. Let $\widetilde{\phi}_{1}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the restriction of $\widetilde{\phi}$ to $\mathbb{R} \times\{1\}$, which is canonically identified with $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\widetilde{\phi}_{1}$ is a lift to $\mathbb{R}$ of the identity map on one of the boundary components of $A$, it is an integer translation. We define $\rho(f)$ to be $\widetilde{\phi}_{1}(0)$. If we identify $\mathbb{Z}$ with the group of integer translations of $\mathbb{R}$, then the map $\widetilde{\phi}_{1}$ itself is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$, and we can write $\rho(f)=\widetilde{\phi}_{1} \in \mathbb{Z}$. From this point of view, it is clear that $\rho$ is a homomorphism since compositions of maps of $A$ are sent to compositions of translations of $\mathbb{R}$.

We can give an equivalent definition of $\rho$ as follows. Let $\delta$ be an oriented simple proper arc that connects the two boundary components of $A$. Given $f$ and $\phi$ as above, the concatenation $\phi(\delta) * \delta^{-1}$ is a loop based at $\delta(0)$, and $\rho(f)$ equals $\left[\phi(\delta) * \delta^{-1}\right] \in \pi_{1}(A, \delta(0)) \approx \mathbb{Z}$. Yet another equivalent way to define $\rho$ is to let $\widetilde{\delta}$ be the unique lift of $\delta$ to $\widetilde{A}$ based at the origin and to set $\rho(f)$ to be the endpoint of $\widetilde{\phi}(\widetilde{\delta})$ in $\mathbb{R} \times\{1\} \approx \mathbb{R}$.

**We now show that $\rho$ is surjective.** The linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ given by the matrix
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & n \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
preserves $\mathbb{R} \times[0,1]$ and is equivariant with respect to the group of deck transformations. Thus the restriction of the linear map $M$ to $\mathbb{R} \times[0,1]$ descends to a homeomorphism $\phi$ of $A$. The action of this homeomorphism on $\delta$ is depicted in Figure $2.5$ for the case $n=-1$. It follows from the definition of $\rho$ that **$\rho([\phi])=n$**.

> why  $\rho$ is surjective ? why $\phi$ is homeomorphism ?  what is exactly homeomorphism $\phi$ of $A$ such that $\rho([\phi])=n$ ? why $\rho([\phi])=n$ ? also what is definition of preferred lift ?

i think we have  $T_{M}:\mathbb R\times [0,1]\to \mathbb R\times [0,1]$ (or  linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ given by the matrix $M$) is the covering map. If $x\in A$, you can pick a $y\in T_{M}^{-1}(x)$. Thanks to the equivariance property, $\phi(x) = T_{M}(My)=M^2y$ does not depend on the choice of $y$. Local triviality gives you the continuity of $\phi$. how we can show  $\rho([\phi])=n$ ?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the internet.  There is no need to write sentences (like titles) in all caps. This etiquette has been in place for perhaps 40 years.  Please remember this in your future work on the internet. thank you. Otherwise good post though.